# PHP LDAP AUTHENTICATION FAILS

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I am trying to authenticate the email id and password using PHP LDAP. Just I want to authenticate no need to access contacts or mails or calendars. Just need to confirm he is the valid user. Host name is correct. Port nos also correct. Please help.
Please note my scenario

1. my mail id is xxxxx@childcompany.com and username is yyyyyy
2. my mail is hosted and handled by Parent company (mail.parentcompany.com )

   ```
   $username = 'yyyyyy@parentcompany.com'; //If i use this line Unable to bind to server: Strong(er) authentication required 
   $username = 'yyyyyy';//If i use this line Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
   $username = 'xxxxx@childcompany.com' //If i use this line Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
   $password = 'mypassword';
   $ldap = ldap_connect("10.1.1.1",389)   ;  
   if ($ldap) 
   {   
      $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap,$username,$password );     
     if ($ldapbind) {
       echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
       echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: What's your user's DN on the LDAP server? Without knowing that, you'll have a hard time getting this to work.

Comment: sorry @RobbyCornelissen .. you are asking Domain Component am i right ?

Comment: Nope. Distinguished name that uniquely identifies user on the LDAP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592. It's a simple ldap-bind example that shows how to authenticate a user against LDAP with any given attribute. Might help you also.

I'd also advise you to check whether the information you get back actually is what you expect by using a console-tool like 'ldapsearch'.

You can use that also to test the ldap-bind by providing credentials like `ldapsearch -h <host> -D <bindDN> -W`. The -W will prompt for the password of the user identified by `<bindDN>`

Comment: hi @heiglandreas https://gist.github.com/5689592.git link is not working.. can u plz update the correct link

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Just changed the link to the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

Let me get it right, your user enters his email and password, and you want to authenticate him based on this? The username you mentioned as yyyyyyy is your user for LDAP search connectivity? Or user enters yyyyyy as his username?

If your user enters email and password (only), usually to get it to work correctly you need a user that has search  privileges on the directory (yyyyyy) that you are doing binding with if you want to look-up your end user by email (pay attention that you might get more than one record, if multiple accounts with same email allowed)

The general idea in this case is to bind with your application user to the directory, do an LDAP query for the DN of the user by his email, and then do additional binding to test the DN you found with the password provided by the user.

You should also check login structure, sometimes username should be prefixed with short domain like 'mydomain\username' for logging into the ldap.

Since there is no easy way to debug binding problems, I also use Wireshark/TCPDump to monitor the traffic to/from LDAP server (it is not SSL encrypted in my case) and I see what is exactly sent to and received from the server.

Comment: Just they will enter yyyyy as username and their password. I need to validate this user login credentials are correct or not. If they are correct I will return Success

Comment: You should also check login structure, sometimes username should be prefixed with short domain like 'mydomain\username' for logging into the ldap.

Since there is no easy way to debug binding problems, I also use Wireshark/TCPDump to monitor the traffic to/from LDAP server (it is not SSL encrypted in my case) and I see what is exactly sent to and received from the server.

Comment: Regarding the DN comment by @RobbyCornelissen, your DN should look like:

CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM